# When encrypting twice with two separate keys, can a single key decrypt both steps?

Tags: encryption, symmetric

Is it possible that if a plaintext is encrypted first with a key, $n_1$, and then this ciphertext is again encrypted using the same algorithm but a different key, $n_2$ that the resulting ciphertext could be converted back to the original plaintext with a single key?

For example:
keys $n_1$, $n_2$, and $n_3$

$p_1$ = "plaintext"

$p_2 = C(n_1, p_1)$

$p_3 = C(n_2, p_2)$

Is  this possible:  $Dec(n_3, p_3) = p_1$?   (where $C$ is an encryption algorithm taking the key and plaintext)

An example I can think of is the Caesar Cipher (the key can be seen as the shift). Where first a shift of 4 is used, and then a shift of 6. A shift of 16 would reveal the plaintext in a single operation (a single key).

Obviously this is a trivial example. Are there any cases where this could happen with a stronger algorithm, such as AES?

Comment: Hi, Joseph. The title of your question asks about decrypting with a third key, but then you wrote $C(n_3, p_3) = p_1$. Do you want the encryption algorithm to work as a decryption when used with the third key $n_3$ or that equation should be something like $Dec(c_3, p_3) = p_1$?

Comment: Hilder Vítor Lima Pereira You're right, I'll change that. Thanks.

Comment: The expression describing this is commutative encryption, see [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6573/are-there-any-secure-commutative-ciphers). It does not work for today's symmetric ciphers.

Comment: @tylo a cipher is commutative if $Enc_{k_1}(Enc_{k_2}(m)) = Enc_{k_2}(Enc_{k_1}(m))$? If yes, then this is not what the question is asking... The searched property here is $Dec_{k_3}(Enc_{k_2}(Enc_{k_1}(m))) = m$, which implies only $Enc_{k_2}(Enc_{k_1}(m)) = Enc_{k_3}(m)$

Comment: @tylo, no, this is asking if encryption under some cipher forms a [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)), and commutativity is neither necessary nor sufficient for something to be a group.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible with the old Pohlig-Hellman cipher.

Here's how it works:

- The global parameter is a prime $p$
- A secret key is a value $k$ which is relatively prime to $p-1$
- To encrypt a message $M$, you compute $C = M^k \bmod p$, and that's you
- To decrypt a ciphertext $C$, you compute $k^{-1} \bmod p-1$, and then compute $M = C^{k^{-1}} \bmod p-1$

With this system, if you encrypt with $k_1$, and then with $k_2$, the resulting ciphertext is $C = (M^{k_1} \bmod p)^{k_2} \bmod p = M^{k_1k_2} \bmod p$; hence, this is identical to encrypting with the key $k_1k_2 \bmod p-1$, and so can be decrypted by that key.

Answer (score 3):

1. You cannot understand encryption as a Caesar Cipher. Caesar cipher is just a simple kind of linear transformation. Two linear operations (e.g., + - * / shift bits, etc) can be combined into one single operation easily.
2. AES definitely cannot. AES consists of 10 rounds of calculations. Each round consists of both linear & non-linear steps. There is no relations between different keys, in your case they are n1, n2, n3.