# How to secure a mental poker protocol?

Tags: block-cipher, protocol-design, mental-poker

I would like to implement a [mental poker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_poker) protocol in a secure fashion. How should I go about that without (preferably) infringing on the [Mental Poker Framework patent](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/4001/843)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about implementing something to avoid patent infringement. This site deals with cryptography from a theoretical prospective.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, if you want advice on a specific patent, I'm afraid you are most likely going to need to consult with a lawyer.  The odds of getting reliable authoritative advice over the Internet are... not so great, in my experience.  Generally speaking, this site focuses primarily on technical questions (which are answerable by many in the community here) rather than legal questions (which few here are experts on).  Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Comment: Well, then an answer about how to implement the protocol safely disregarding the legal aspect would be welcome.

Comment: @ThePiachu, the Wikipedia article you link to includes citations for [SCH98], [STA05], and [GOL05].  Have you read those articles?  Do you understand their protocols?  They would be a good place to start.  No one here is likely to write a detailed tutorial that will spare you the need to read the original research papers.  However, if you do the reading and get as far as you can on your own, if you find you get stuck somewhere specific, it's possible people might be able to help you if you can explain where you got stuck and what you tried.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to those articles, I will read up on them.