# Cryptographic system with double keys with reversible order

Tags: encryption, mental-poker

While reading Shamir, Rivest and Adleman's paper on "Mental Poker", I've met a mention of system such that $E_a(E_b(x)) = E_b(E_a(x))$, without however disclosing details on it, with $E_a(x)$ being “encrypt plaintext $x$ with key $a$”.

Do any existing secure modern cryptosystems have this property, and how is it called for later reference?

Comment: This property means that the encryption is *commutative*. One example of a commutative encryption operation would be *xor*.
Here are some [related](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/6573/8911) [questions](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1363/8911).  In general a secure scheme is unlikely to have this property since unless required it exposes a potential weakness

Comment: Your definition would not be compatible with probabilistic encryption. I am wondering if this similar definition would work better $D_a(D_b(E_a(E_b(m))))=m$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, remark that the desired **commutativity is incompatible with security under [Chosen Plaintext Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-plaintext_attack)**, which (under the name [IND-CPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability#Indistinguishability_under_chosen-plaintext_attack_.28IND-CPA.29)) is considered a requirement for modern encryption systems. Proof, expanded following [tylo](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/4082/tylo)'s [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15289/cryptographic-system-with-double-keys-with-reversible-order#comment31969_15293), using the IND-CPA game as played for symmetric encryption (see the *CPA indistinguishability experiment* in section 3.5 of Katz and Lindell's [Introduction to modern cryptography](http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781584885511), also [here](http://www3.nd.edu/~cse/2013fa/60622/lecture05.pdf) on page 4):

- We assume a cipher $E$:

  - commutative as in the question, that is: $\forall a,\forall b,\forall x, E_a(E_b(x))=E_b(E_a(x))$;
  - injective: $\forall a,\forall x,\forall y, E_a(x)=E_a(y)\implies x=y$ (a necessity for reliable decryption);
  - $E$ can be [deterministic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm) or [probabilistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_encryption); in the later case $E$ has some randomness source as a hidden input beyond key (the subscript) and data (the explicit parameter), and the above properties hold for all values of the random inputs in each instance of $E$;
  - the cipher has a public definition (except for its randomness soure if any) allowing its practical implementation by the adversary (an algorithm with time and space complexity polynomial in the size of the parameters);
- the game starts with the referee choosing and announcing the size of parameters;
- the referee secretly chooses a random key $k$;
- the adversary chooses a random key $r$, a random plaintext $X$, and computes $M_0=E_r(X)$ using the cipher's definition, until $M_0\ne X$ (which holds with high odds for any secure cipher);
- in a training phase, the adversary submits $X$ for encryption and obtains $Y=E_k(X)$;
- in the challenge phase

  - the adversary submits $M_0$, and any $M_1$ that is neither $M_0$ nor $X$ (submitting $M_1=M_0$ would be poor strategy; submitting $M_0$ or $M_1$ that was submitted in the training phase would be against the rules of the game played for deterministic encryption);
  - the referee secretly chooses $i$ randomly in $\{0,1\}$ by fair coin toss, and returns $C=E_k(M_b)$;
- (here the rule of the game allows the adversary to make other queries for encryption under key $k$, bound to be for messages different from $M_0$ and $M_1$ in the game played for deterministic encryption);
- the adversary returns $i'=0$ if $C=E_r(Y)$, which is computable using the cipher's definition, or $i'=1$ otherwise;
- the adversary wins if $i'=i$ (and we want the odds of that, which should be better than $1/2$ by some $\epsilon>0$ independent of the size of the parameters);

  - if the referee picked $i=0$: $C=E_k(M_0)=E_k(E_r(X))$, and applying the commutativity property of the cipher we get $C=E_r(E_k(X))=E_r(Y)$, thus $i'=0$;
  - if the referee picked $i=1$: since $M_1\ne M_0$, and because the cipher is injective, $C=E_k(M_1)$ must be different from whatever $E_k(M_0)$ would have been, which (as shown above) is bound to match $E_r(Y)$ that was computed by the adversary and used to find $i'$, thus $i'=1$ (note: in the case of a probabilistic algorithm, one could think there potentially could be several $E_k(M_0)$, but the commutativity property makes it necessary that they all match $E_r(Y)$ as computed by the adversary: in order to be commutative, the cipher is bound to be deterministic for inputs $M_0$ and $Y$ given how these have been generated);
  - thus with certainty, $i'=i$ (this is a perfect [distinguisher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distinguishing_attack)).

---

As [remarked](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15289/cryptographic-system-with-double-keys-with-reversible-order#comment31788_15289) by [figlesquidge](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/8911/figlesquidge), XOR with a [One Time Pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Time_Pad) has the desired commutativity property, in some sense. That's also true for any [Stream Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Cipher) with an out-of-band method for synchronization (including a [block cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) such as [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) in [OFB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Output_feedback#Output_feedback_.28OFB.29) or [CTR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Output_feedback#Counter_.28CTR.29) mode, with out-of-band [IV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector)); by *out-of-band* I mean: not part of the [ciphertext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext) for which the commutativity property is thought.

However the OTP or other out-of-band data is often impractical (in particular it won't work in use cases where several ciphertexts are shuffled but out-of-band data has not, which is the situation in Mental Poker), and do not match the definition of a cipher (which requires reusable key and no out-of-band data).

---

We study the simplest commutative cipher in the cryptographic folklore, sometime used for [Mental Poker](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/ShamirRivestAdleman-MentalPoker.pdf):

#### The [Pohlig-Hellman Exponentiation Cipher](http://www-ee.stanford.edu/~hellman/publications/28.pdf)

For a given public odd prime $p$, let $K$ be the set of $k\in\mathbb N$ with $0<k<p$ that are [coprime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers) with $p-1$, and $*$ multiplication modulo $p-1$, so that $(K,*)$ is a commutative group with $k=1$ the neutral element.

The Pohlig-Hellman Exponentiation Cipher over $\mathbb Z_p$ with key in $k$ is
$$\begin{align}
E:K\times\mathbb Z_p&\mapsto \mathbb Z_p\\
(k,x)&\mapsto E(k,x)=x^k\bmod p=E_k(x)
\end{align}$$

Encryption with key $k$ is $E_k: x\mapsto E_k(x)$ and is a permutation of $\mathbb Z_p$. The set of the permutations obtained form a group under function composition (noted $\circ$), isomorphic to $(K,*)$:
$$\forall a\in K,\forall b\in K,\forall x\in \mathbb Z_p,E_b(E_a(x))=(E_b\circ E_a)(x)=E_{b*a}(x)$$
As a consequence, decryption is $D_k=E_\overline k$, with $\overline k=k^{-1}\bmod(p-1)$ the inverse of $k$ in group $(K,*)$; and the desired commutativity property holds:
$$\forall a\in K,\forall b\in K,\forall x\in \mathbb Z_p, E_a(E_b(x))=E_b(E_a(x))$$

For appropriate $p$ (making the [Discrete Logarithm Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) hard), the cipher is conjectured secure for multiple random plaintexts related to the same random key [that's stated before (15) in the original article, linked to the title of this section; and justified by an argument I do not get]. However, it has a number of other properties that a random commutative cipher would not obviously have, including the multiplicative property $\pmod p$:

$$\forall k\in K,\forall x\in \mathbb Z_p,\forall y\in \mathbb Z_p, E_k(x\cdot y\bmod p)=E_k(x)\cdot E_k(y)\bmod p$$

There are a number of other undesirable properties:

1. Three fixed points: $\forall x\in\{0,1,p-1\},\forall k\in K,E_k(x)=x$
2. A symmetry in the message space: $\forall x\in \mathbb Z_p,\forall k\in K,E_k(p-x\bmod p)=\big(p-E_k(x)\big)\bmod p$
3. The isomorphism with $(K,*)$ allows some [related-key attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Related-key_attack), and implies a weak key ($k=1$).
4. The keyspace is not an interval of $\mathbb N$, which is inconvenient.

#### A variant

We can fix these 4 issues. Let $p$ be a large public prime with $(p-1)/2$ prime, such as $p=\lfloor\pi\cdot2^{2046}\rfloor+3,617,739$. Let $P$ be the set of $(p-3)/2$ integers $\{2,3\dots,(p-3)/2,(p-1)/2\}$. For key $k$ of 256 bits and data $x\in P$, define
$$\begin{align}
k_E&=2^{320}\cdot\small\text{SHA-256}(k)+2^{64}\cdot k+1\\
k_D&=\overline{k_E}={k_E}^{-1}\bmod (p-1)\\
\mathbf E_k(x)&=\min\big(x^{k_E}\bmod p,p-(x^{k_E}\bmod p)\big)\\
\mathbf D_k(x)&=\min\big(x^{k_D}\bmod p,p-(x^{k_D}\bmod p)\big)
\end{align}$$
Fixed points and symmetry are removed by the definition of $P$ and the use of $\min$. The construction of the exponent $k_E$ makes it coprime with $p-1$ (since $k_E$ is odd and too small to divide the single odd divisor of $p-1$), ensures that any 256-bit $k$ makes a fine key, and provides fair protection against related-key attacks. The construction of $k_D$ ensures that $\forall k,\forall x,\mathbf D_k(\mathbf E_k(x))=x$.

The desired commutativity property still holds, as well as the multiplicative property (be it wanted or not). We can artificially get rid of the multiplicative property by inserting a pseudo-random permutation $M$ of the set $P$ before encryption, and its reverse afterwards: $x\mapsto (M^{-1}\circ\mathbf E_k\circ M)(x)$ still has the commutativity property, but not the multiplicative property; however an adversary knowing $M$ can still potentially get advantage of the multiplicative property.

#### Using RSA encryption padding

If $\small\text{OAEP}(x)$ designates the padding used for [RSA-OAEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_Asymmetric_Encryption_Padding) with a modulus of $\lceil\log_2(p)\rceil$ bits, then $x\mapsto E(\small\text{OAEP}(x))$ seems to be IND-CPA-secure, and decipherable (the desired commutativity property is lost: that padding must be external to whatever step of the protocol requires commutativity). As [pointed](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15289/cryptographic-system-with-double-keys-with-reversible-order#comment31808_15293) by [Ricky Demer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/991/ricky-demer), [OAEP+](http://www.shoup.net/papers/oaep.pdf) is preferable to OAEP.

Both paddings hide the multiplicative property, by means including making the cipher probabilistic.

Comment: One could use [OAEP+](http://www.shoup.net/papers/oaep.pdf) instead of OEAP. $\;$

Comment: Actually, does commutativity survive inserting either of those padding schemes? $\;$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you provide any papers on the protocol you've described? Like, if it's secure, why isn't it widespread?

Comment: @modchan: I found the name (and updated the answer). See also [that answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1366/555) for another suitable algorithm (SRA, which is about the same with $p$ replaced by $n$ of factorization shared between the parties).

Comment: In the IND-CPA game the adversary usually only gets one challenge ciphertext. This still breaks all deterministic encryption, but if $E$ is probabilistic it isn't necessarily the case. However, probabilistic schemes can probably not provide this commutativity.

Comment: out-of-bad $\mapsto$ out-of-band $\;$

Comment: @tylo: Your remark is correct for the IND-CPA game played for public-key encryption, where encryption of chosen plaintext is always possible, and unstated. But for symmetric encryption, the textbook IND-CPA game allows the adversary to obtain a ciphertext for chosen plaintext before the challenge phase (at the price, in the deterministic encryption game, of not choosing it later on). I expanded my sketch to a full proof. Initially it was for deterministic encryption, but with minor tweaks it seems I have now proven that no symmetric scheme (including probabilistic) can provide commutativity!